# Java: Import a class to Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am new to java and I am wondering what is the best way to go about importing a class to a JFrame since I have a few minor applications I would like to make run in a window other then eclipse.

Here is some of the code I am working with (Its a modified version of some code in the dummies book):

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessAgain {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Set up input and main info
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numGuesses = 0;
    int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(10) + 1;

    // Display welcome message
    out.println("~-=********************=-~");
    out.println("    The Guessing Game!    ");
    out.println("~-=********************=-~");

    // Give instruction
    out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 10: ");
    int inputNumber = input.nextInt();
    numGuesses++;

    // Recurse till user gets the answer
    while (inputNumber != randomNumber) {
        out.println();
        out.println("~-=********************=-~");
        out.println("     Please try again     ");
        out.println("~-=********************=-~");
        out.print("Enter another number between 1 and ten: ");
        inputNumber = input.nextInt();
        numGuesses++;
    }
    out.print("You won after: " + numGuesses + " guesses");

}

}
```

So how do I go about putting all of that into a window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably want to take a look at oracle's [swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html), that's what you need to learn how to use in order to make a frame/window. You can make a nice GUI (Graphic User Interface) for your game with that, rather than just using Eclipse's console ;)

Comment: Oh sweet, thanks for that! I feel like a bit of a moron for not checking there first. Oh well no harm no fowl I guess. I'll give that a look! :)

Comment: @CodeMonkeyAlx Yup :) Oracle is the current owner of Java, so they better have some good tutorials ;)

Comment: It kind of stinks that all they use is netbeans but the translation over to eclipse is not to bad if all your working with is the code. I'll be sure to check the answer when I am able to. It gave me an 11 minute timeout on it. My guess is so other people have a chance to answer it as well?

Comment: @CodeMonkeyAlx Yeah, there's not many big differences between NetBeans and Eclipse, except that Eclipse is better :P And 11 minute timeout on what?

Comment: I ended up with message when I tried to accept the answer the first time telling me i had to wait 11 minutes.